# Entity Framework with ADO.NET not updating the view

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, ado, localdb

I am struggling with Entity Framework using ADO.NET not updating the view with the following:

```
public async static Task InsertBackGroundImageAsync(string name, byte[] image)
{
    Entities db = new Entities();
    db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    db.BackgroundImages.Add(new BackgroundImage { Name = name, Image = image });
    db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return;
}
```

I also tried this code:

```
public async static Task InsertBackGroundImageAsync(string name, byte[] image)
{
    Entities db = new Entities();
    db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
    BackgroundImage bgi = new BackgroundImage { Name = name, Image = image };
    db.BackgroundImages.Add(bgi);
    db.Entry(bgi).State = EntityState.Added;
    db.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return;
}
```

None of them work, however, if I work on the entity directly, it does work.

Replacing

```
Entities db = new Entities()
```

with

```
Entities db = IoC.Mainview.DBs
```

which is the current, works.

I should add that the datacontext is passed from CollectionViewSource.
Any pointers?

Comment: Why would that update the view? Are you exposing the entity framework collections direct to the view? That's a bad idea. For anything but trivial apps it's a bad idea to use the ef change tracking since that means you're passing round the one connection all the time.

Comment: I do get your point, but isn't that the Microsoft recommended way? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/databinding/wpf

Comment: How does it "not work"? Exceptions? Not the expected results? Is it just the view? Also, "using ADO.net" is redundant information. EF always uses ADO.net.

Comment: Yes, sorry for ado... It does update the db, just not the view. I pass the DataContext="{StaticResource backgroundImageViewSource} to the control as described in the microsoft link.

Comment: Nope, just doesn't work. Whatever I do, it just doesn't update the view. It's is all set as observablecollection, so i shouldn't have to refresh the list. What am i missing?